# 413 error in the sping-boot application deployed on google-app-engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine

I am new to google-app-engine based deployment. I have my spring-boot application deployed on app-engine and getting 413 while uploading larger size files.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/createProject", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public @ResponseBody Project createProject(@RequestPart(value = "project") Project project, @RequestPart("files") List<MultipartFile> files) throws Exception {
....
}
```

Can someone tell me how to increase the default media size in app-engine configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Requests) the limit for uploads in Google App Engine is 32MB and this cannot be changed. If you are using GAE Standard I recommend you to send requests to Cloud Storage, using the [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) process. This recommendation is explained with a bit more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47287852/8456296). If you use GAE Flex, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040851/8456296) alternative as well, I have never tested it but it consists in customizing a [nginx-app.conf file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#customizing_nginx) file for the nginx server.

Hope it helps! :))