# How to increase client_max_body_size in Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I have an express app running in Google app engine (Flex env) and need to upload file size around 50-60 Mb to static path, But nginx is sending 413 Entity too large. I tried overriding this by adding

`client_max_body_size 100M;`

in my nginx-app.conf file ([found this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038645/how-can-i-edit-the-nginx-configuration-on-google-app-engine-flexible-environment)) but didn't work for some reason.

I have also raised an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112810617), meanwhile need to know if there is a workaround

Comment: Did you get any workaround for this problem? I'm facing something similar on my app.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered on the [issueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112810617).

Direct uploads are limited to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Code. For larger uploads the recommended way is to use the [Blobstore interface](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/)